# When the kree and ksiv sound identical, does intending the ksiv invalidate the reading?

Tags: torah-reading, mistakes

We always read the *k’ree*.

If one read the *k’siv* instead of the *k’ree* the reading is invalid and has to be repeated.  [O Ch 142(8) MB[27]](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.141.8?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en)

In [B’har (25:30)](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.25.30?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)  the *k’ree* and the *k’siv* are phonetically the same (*lo*) but diametrically different in translation (Has/Has not).

If the baal koreh read the word with the intention of the *k’siv* (i.e. he read it as “…**not** have a wall) instead of the *k’ree* (it **has** a wall) is his reading valid?

I heard from Rav Chaim Kanievsky that there is no requirement to repeat.

Is there any further discussion about this type of reading error?

(This occurrence is mentioned in [this article](https://www.betemunah.org/kri&ktiv.html#_Toc360710034) on the subject.)

Comment: Not sure how this would be different from any other time someone doesn't know what a word means while reading or other words that sound similar in your idiolect (eg. פסח and פתח)

Comment: Practically, *gabbaim* would have no way to correct *kavanna* like this. I can't see this being any different than the *ba'al kri'ah* reading any other sections of the torah without knowing or concentrating on the words' meanings. Offhand, I can tell you than when I read most of *Ha'azinu*, I don't understand most of it.